# How to add camera functionality in windows app using Project Reunion template for WinUI 3.0 desktop app?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, winui, winui-3

I'm developing a desktop application using Project Reunion WinUI template in Visual Studio 2019. We have requirement that we need to capture image from our application and save it.

I tried **CameraCaptureUI** (this works in UWP application, but not in Project Reunion)

Code:

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
if (file == null)
{
}
```

Error:

[image: Error]

We tried using **CaptureElement** [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement?view=winrt-20348), but it is not supported in Project Reunion.

Let me know what I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not available in WinUI3 (Reunion).

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4710

Comment: yes, CameraCaptureUI  and many other controls are not supported in WinUI3 (Reunion) yet. I have already switched to UWP.